# Where to put Hunspell dictionary for Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, hunspell

The Elasticsearch Hunspell [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/hunspell.html) say to put the dictionaries 
in config/hunspell

Is it

```
/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/hunspell/
```

or

```
/etc/elasticsearch/config/hunspell/
```

or

```
/etc/elasticsearch/hunspell/
```

or something else?

So far, I've tried all of those with no success.

There is some talk about a similar issue in this [bug report](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-definitive-guide/issues/495), but I don't see an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of the directory structure for Elasticsearch 5 installed using the .deb installer:

```
# Elasticsearch home directory
#ES_HOME=/usr/share/elasticsearch

# Elasticsearch configuration directory
#CONF_DIR=/etc/elasticsearch

# Elasticsearch data directory
#DATA_DIR=/var/lib/elasticsearch

# Elasticsearch logs directory
#LOG_DIR=/var/log/elasticsearch

# Elasticsearch PID directory
#PID_DIR=/var/run/elasticsearch
```

In this case, the Hunspell dictionaries should be in a folder called `/hunspell` in the config directory, which in this particular case would be:
`/etc/elasticsearch/hunspell`

Answer (score 3):

For the version 6.5.1, no need to create `config` directory

`/usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/hunspell` place all language folders here.

```
-- hunspell
     |    |-- en_US
     |    |    |-- en_US.dic
     |    |    |-- en_US.aff
     |    |-- ru_RU
     |    |    |-- ru_RU.dic
     |    |    |-- ru_RU.aff
```

After that just restart the elasticsearch service.

After the installation you will see this.

```
\Data:    /usr/local/var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_bira/
Logs:    /usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_bira.log
Plugins: /usr/local/var/elasticsearch/plugins/
Config:  /usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/
```

Answer (score 1):

> The location of the Hunspell directory can be changed by setting
>   indices.analysis.hunspell.dictionary.location in the
>   config/elasticsearch.yml file.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/hunspell.html

Answer (score 0):

Structure of elasticsearch/config must be

```
- conf
     |-- hunspell
     |    |-- en_US
     |    |    |-- en_US.dic
     |    |    |-- en_US.aff
     |    |-- ru_RU
     |    |    |-- ru_RU.dic
     |    |    |-- ru_RU.aff
```

Answer (score -1):

Turns out that the symbolic links are not followed by elasticsearch (see [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15581)), so the ACTUAL files need to be at the location specified.

Also, the file permissions for the hunspell files need to allow the elasticsearch user to access them.
Ex (in /etc/elasticsearch/hunspell/):

> drwxr-xr-x 2 root elasticsearch 4.0K Sep  9 09:24 nl_NL

Comment: Can you at least specify which directory you put your hunspell dictionaries? Thanks

Comment: That depends on the installation method (and the elasticsearch version), so it's better to look where your copy has been installed. Then just put the hunspell directory next to your config file.